# ServiceStackVS TypeScript Reference (.d.ts) Errors - "Cannot find name 'Nullable'."

Tags: visual-studio-2015, servicestack, visual-studio-extensions

When adding a TypeScript Reference using ServiceStackVS, the resulting .d.ts file generates an error, "Cannot find name 'Nullable'.", for any Request DTO properties that are arrays.  For example, I have a Request DTO for finding Events:

```
public class FindEvents : QueryBase<Event> {
    ...

    [QueryField(Template = "{Field} BETWEEN {Value1} AND {Value2}", Field = "StartDateTime")]
    public DateTime?[] DateBetween { get; set; }

    [QueryField(Template = "MONTH({Field}) BETWEEN {Value1} AND {Value2}", Field = "StartDateTime")]
    public int?[] MonthBetween { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The generated interface for this Request DTO looks like:

```
interface FindEvents extends QueryBase_1<Event>, IReturn<QueryResponse<Event>>
{
    ...

    DateBetween?: Nullable;
    MonthBetween?: Nullable;
    ...

}
```

The generated type "Nullable" is what's causing the error.

In the service, I can change `DateTime?[]` and `int?[]` to `string[]` and that will generate `DateBetween?: string[];` and `MonthBetween?: string[];` respectively.

That will work - in the service and in the TypeScript code - but I would prefer not to change the service in that way.

Any suggestions?  Can ServiceStackVS be updated to handle Request DTO properties that are arrays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are already nullable reference types in .NET so you don't need to specify it contains nullable value types as well.

AutoQuery also doesn't handle arrays where some of the ValueTypes are `null`, so you should just change the arrays to non-nullable Value Types, e.g:

```
public class FindEvents : QueryBase<Event> 
{
    [QueryField(Template = "{Field} BETWEEN {Value1} AND {Value2}", Field = "StartDateTime")]
    public DateTime[] DateBetween { get; set; }

    [QueryField(Template = "MONTH({Field}) BETWEEN {Value1} AND {Value2}", Field = "StartDateTime")]
    public int[] MonthBetween { get; set; }
}
```

This ends up providing a nicer strong-typed API whilst the properties remain optional.

> Note: DateTime's are emitted as strings in TypeScript to match how they're sent in JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Demis - great as always!